# using requests.get to find simple product information from store websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to make a simple program that lets the user search for a product simultaneously on three popular grocery store websites, namely Meijer, Aldi, and Walmart. When I try and run a request the meijer site such as below, I get a connection error message along with multiple lines of exceptions (full example in comments)

```
search_query = input("Search for:\t")
meijer_params = {"text": search_query}
request_meijer = requests.get("https://www.meijer.com/shop/en/search/", params = meijer_params )
print(request_meijer.url)
```

I also am having issues getting the requests from Aldis to process, using the following, where search query is defined as previously mentioned

```
request_aldi = requests.get("https://shop.aldi.us/store/aldi/search_v3/" + search_query)
print(request_aldi.url)
```

I tried using `str(search_query)` to make sure `search_query` was typecast properly but to no avail. I also tried making the URL that I needed to search a string, concatenating that string with `search_query`, such as:

```
aldi_url = "https://shop.aldi.us/store/aldi/search_v3/" + search_query
```

and

```
aldi_url = "https://shop.aldi.us/store/aldi/search_v3/" + str(search_query)
```

however, these did not work either.

any suggestions as to how I could properly request these sites would be greatly appreciated. The ultimate goal is to use BeautifulSoup to parse the data and extract things like container sizes and prices for the queried items

Comment: Meijer site request error report readout: https://pastebin.com/wHA9XpUX

Answer (score 0):

To get correct pages and/or not get connection timeout in these cases, use `User-Agent` HTTTP header.

For example:

```
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

search_query = 'bottle'
meijer_params = {"text": 'bottle'}
request_meijer = requests.get("https://www.meijer.com/shop/en/search/", params=meijer_params, headers=headers)
print(request_meijer.url)

request_aldi = requests.get("https://shop.aldi.us/store/aldi/search_v3/" + search_query, headers=headers)
print(request_aldi.url)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.meijer.com/shop/en/search/?text=bottle
https://shop.aldi.us
```